# ReactiveCocoa finally never be called with already completed replaySubject. Is it expected behavior?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

Is this expected behavior?

```
RACSubject *subject = [RACReplaySubject replaySubjectWithCapacity:1];
[subject sendCompleted];
[subject finally:^{
    NSLog(@"never called");
}];
[subject subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"called");
}];
```

If so, how do I have `finally` like block? Do I need like this?

```
void (^block)() = ^ {
    NSLog(@"like finally!");
};
[subject subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
    block();
} completed:^{
    block();
}];
```

EDIT: For those who misunderstand what `finally` do like me, [the document for renamed `doFinished` in RAC 3.0](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/3.0-development/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L318-L329) may help you understand, instead of [the 2.X document](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/v2.3/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L118-L124).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually unrelated to the fact that the signal has already completed. Consider this:

```
RACSubject *subject = [RACSubject subject];
[subject finally:^{
    NSLog(@"never called");
}];
[subject subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"called");
}];
[subject sendCompleted];
```

Still never called! Why? Because `finally:` returns a new signal; it doesn't modify the existing signal. The new signal will perform those side effects whenever it sends a `completed` or `error` to one of its subscribers. If it doesn't have any subscribers, those side effects will never take place. So now let's subscribe to the signal that `finally:` returns:

```
RACSubject *subject = [RACReplaySubject replaySubjectWithCapacity:1];
[subject sendCompleted];
[[subject finally:^{
    NSLog(@"called now!");
}] subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"called");
}];
```

That works, but might not be what you actually want. `finally:` doesn't inject side effects into the *signal*, it injects side effects into *each subscription to the signal*. So the following thing:

```
RACSubject *subject = [RACReplaySubject replaySubjectWithCapacity:1];
[subject sendCompleted];
RACSignal *signalWithFinally = [subject finally:^{
    NSLog(@"finally block");
}];
[signalWithFinally subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"first subscriber completed");
}];
[signalWithFinally subscribeCompleted:^{
    NSLog(@"second subscriber completed");
}];
```

Will perform the `finally:` block *twice*, which may not be what you want. `subscribeError:completed:` may be a better choice for your use case.

Comment: Thanks! I found that I misunderstood how `finally` works. I may use `subscribeError:completed:`.